# Audit Complete Entity in existing DB Table

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a User entity having around 12 properties. When end user updates any of the User detail, I need to delete this particular User's row from User_Db table and insert in User_Hist table and insert updated User Entity in User_Db table. How can this be achieved in Spring Data JPA?

Appreciate any help provided!!

I read about Hibernate Envers and about Spring Data JPA Auditing, however it creates its own table and audits only few columns. I need to handle complete entity(row deletion) and in existing table.

Comment: Why would you need to delete the existing row and recreate it. That is madness. Surely you would just update it.

Comment: The User_Hist table is audited regularly for various Business purposes. Need to have this feature

Comment: Envers does exactly what you need. Not sure why you think it doesn't.

Comment: I don't need RevInfo table generated by Enver. Also I don't need to log the Revision number or Revision Type in Audited Entity.

Comment: You'll need to write you own auditing framework then.